# PHP shell_exec won't call Windows 10 bash script

Tags: php, bash, windows-10, shell-exec

I'm running a CakePHP project under XAMPP (Apache) on Windows 10 Anniversary Update.

Apache is running under my user account.

The app calls several external processes via shell_exec(): ImageMagick, phantomjs execute as expected.

I also want to call a bash script, that in turn calls ImageMagick under Ubuntu bash (installed separately, via apt-get). I've had to adjust all paths into a form that bash can resolve.

````
bash /mnt/e/Projects/project-name/website/bin/crop_to_aspect.sh 1 1
/mnt/e/Projects/project-name/website/webroot/images/agent_photo/tmp_ed564289-a6f6-45b7-b9f3-2aec2b8bb3d1.jpg
/mnt/e/Projects/project-name/website/webroot/images/agent_photo/ed564289-a6f6-45b7-b9f3-2aec2b8bb3d1.jpg```
````

The command fails when called via shell_exec(). The same command, written to CakePHP's log, and then called from a `cmd.exe` prompt, works perfectly.

Thinking it may have been a path issue, I wrapped the same script in a windows batch file, including the full path to bash. I called the full batch file path, ie:

```
@echo off

SET aw=%1
SET ah=%2
SET in=%3
SET out=%4
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe /mnt/e/Projects/project-path/website/bin/crop_to_aspect.sh %aw% %ah% %in% %out%
```

This script is then called:

```
E:\Projects\project-path\website\bin\crop_to_aspect.bat 4 3
 /mnt/e/Projects/project-path/website/webroot/images/listing_photo/tmp_ed564289-a6f6-45b7-b9f3-2aec2b8bb3d1.jpg
/mnt/e/Projects/project-path/website/webroot/images/listing_photo/ed564289-a6f6-45b7-b9f3-2aec2b8bb3d1.jpg
```

Once again, the command executes correctly in `cmd.exe` but does nothing when run via shell_exec() from the PHP script.

Comment: Might be worth rewriting the script into native PHP using http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php no portability issues that way

Comment: fair call, I'm working with someone else's codebase, developed on linux, but the shell script would be pretty trivial to rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Check if a function is not in the list of functions disabled in php.ini (disable_functions) line